# How to find out which HDD/SSD disk causes boot failures?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have Windows 10 and several attached HDD /SSD disks. My system doesn't boot from time to time. It hangs during startup at the very beginning with the message: Detected ATA devices...

What is the right way to find bad disk? I tried to check every disk with built in utilities, but no luck...

What else can I try?

UPD:

Hangs at message [image: startup message]
Few Subsequent restarts help OS loads.

I tried to detach disks one by one. It didn't help...  I wasn't able to determine bad disk.

Comment: When it hangs during startup, what do you do to fix it?

Comment: Simply detach each disk one by one and check if the problem occurs again (You probably should perform multiple pc restarts to speed the whole trial and error process up.).

Comment: your BIOS is from 2013. Have you checked to see if there is a BIOS update for you motherboard? http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/990FX%20Extreme9/?cat=Download&os=BIOS